# Spring managed transactions without @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I'm using Spring annotations to manage my transactions like so:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class AlertServiceImpl implements AlertService {

     private AlertDAO alertDAO;

     public List<Alert> getAlerts(){
         List<Alert> alerts = alertDAO.getAlerts();
         return alerts;
     }

}
```

I'm wondering what happens if I forget the annotation:

```
// Oops! Forgot to use transactional annotation 
public class AlertServiceImpl implements AlertService {

    private AlertDAO alertDAO;

    public List<Alert> getAlerts(){
         List<Alert> alerts = alertDAO.getAlerts();
         return alerts;
    }

}
```

When the alertDAO implementation is following:

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

// no annotation here either
public class HibernateAlertDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport implements AlertDAO {

    public List<Alert> getAlerts(){
         // some implementation details that define queryString

         Query query = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
         List<Alert> alerts = query.list();

         return alerts;
    }

}
```

It seems like Hibernate allows me to fetch data from database even without the annotation.

What are the consequences of this kind of carelessness and what are the worst case scenarios that could happen?

Comment: Regarding your question you can get a session drain, i.e. sessions are opened but never closed due to the absence of a transaction boundary (which spring uses to open/close sessions). Your dao is flawed you should not call `getSession` on the `HibernateDaoSupport` class (this will open an unmanaged session). (`HibernateTemplate` and `HibernateDaoSupport` must be considered deprecated as of Hibernate 3.0.1 somewhere in 2006!). See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight.

Comment: Is the transactional boundary not, by default, either where the service call returns or where the serving thread (in the case of a webapp) returns the MVC request?  If it's a non-web-app scenario then yes, session drain is a big problem. However, as it' always calling getSession() that'll return the current session if it exists won't it?  As it's stored on the Thread Local?

Comment: @M.Deinum can you provide your inputs on similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831749/hibernate-session-with-spring-transaction ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the documentation ([Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/transaction.html)) it's just metadata to give an indication that the method or interface can be configured by something that is 'transactionally aware' (i.e. `<tx:annotation-driven/>`).

With just **tx:annotation-driven** and no `@Transactional` attribute I believe you get the "default" transactionality applied:

- Propagation setting is *REQUIRED*.
- Isolation level is *DEFAULT*.
- Transaction is read/write.
- Transaction timeout defaults to the default timeout of the underlying transaction system, or none if timeouts are not supported.
- any *RuntimeException* triggers rollback, and any checked *Exception* does not.

Assuming you're using the `<tx:annotation-driven />` to drive it via a transaction manager then missing out the `@Transactional` attribute means you can't apply such properties as *readOnly*, *isolation*, *propagation*, *rollbackFor*, *noRollbackFor* etc.

I believe that MVC is slightly different - the Hibernate session is tied directly to the MVC request - i.e. when the request is received the transaction starts.

Back to your example, the code for getSession() in HibernateDAOSupport is as follows:

```java
protected final Session getSession()
    throws DataAccessResourceFailureException, IllegalStateException 
{
    return getSession(this.hibernateTemplate.isAllowCreate());
}
```

Which in turn calls to:

```java
/**
 * Obtain a Hibernate Session, either from the current transaction or
 * a new one. The latter is only allowed if "allowCreate" is true.
 *.......
 */
protected final Session getSession()
    throws DataAccessResourceFailureException, IllegalStateException {
    return getSession(this.hibernateTemplate.isAllowCreate());
}
```

which ultimately calls to :

```java
/** 
 * ....
 * @param allowCreate whether a non-transactional Session should be created
 * when no transactional Session can be found for the current thread
 * ....
 */
private static Session doGetSession(
    SessionFactory sessionFactory, Interceptor entityInterceptor,
SQLExceptionTranslator jdbcExceptionTranslator, boolean allowCreate)
```

Fundamentally, a Transaction:Session is tied 1:1 AFAIK, and the only way to run without a transaction is by using say JBoss which has a 'baked in' persistence layer which provides the transactionality for you (under the covers).  Even if you call `getQuery()` after `getSession()` you still effectively have a transaction occurring as it's a JDBC/Hibernate connection.

Comment: Spring repositories .save/.saveAll methods are already transactional, so no need to annotate your service unless you want to group several Save calls into one single transaction. On the other hand DAO methods and JDBC Templates are not transactional by default,so they should be called inside @Transactional methods

Answer (score 4):

In your scenario your DAO will execute without transaction, most probably with auto-commit.

If you want to avoid this kind of mistake in future and require all your services to run in transaction you can protect DAO layer with following `@Transactional` annotation:

```
@Transactional(propagation = MANDATORY)
public class HibernateAlertDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport implements AlertDAO {
   ...
}
```

This annotation will require service layer to declare transaction and will throw exception otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Without the annotation, you lose the advantages of the transactions like the rollbacks.

With the @Transactional annotation you are doing more than one database operation, like many inserts and one fails, all the operations in the transaction can rollback to give consistency to your data.

That is also why it's recommended to put the annotation in the services not in the DAOs.

Comment: "No rollbacks or transactions"? No - you still have rollbacks on non-checked Exceptions RTE derivatives, and whatever transactionality has either been configured with the spring-config or supplied as a Spring default?

Comment: If you are using declarative transaction management, of course it won't affect to the way rollbacks work, but if you depend exclusively from the annotation, it will affect the way a set of database operations behave.

Answer (score -7):

Nothing would happen if you not put the @transactional Annotation Basically @Transactional is not mandatory to put on the top of method signature  it is just use to inform compiler when your transactional is read only=true (only for the data retrieval purpose) and when it is  read only=false(only for the insert update delete operations)