# is transaction management applicalble without using @transactional over a method

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-transactions

Have the following configuration in a java project-

```
<bean id="testTxManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="testDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="testTxManager" />
    </bean>
```

But in the DOA java class, **@transactional is not used over any of the methods.
Will Transaction management be still applicable on these methods?**

Comment: Have a look over following answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21314483/2002966