# Fetching data without transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Below is the sample code snippet with spring transaction . My question :-Will same session be used for fetching entities at line1 and line2 ?

My understanding :- I believe yes and it will be ensured by spring transaction

```
@Transactional()
    public void method1(
     //fetch entity1 from dao  with the help of entity manager//line 1

     // fetch entity2 from dao with the help of entity manager//line 2

    // now I fetch thru method entity.fetchLazyField()// line 3
    )
```

Now if i remove `@Transactional()`. I believe session will be closed as soon as entity1 is fetched and separate session will be used for line2. Right ?

At line 3(once  `@Transactional` is removed) , will I be able to fetch data or session is closed exception should be thrown  ?

I am not pasting big xml configuration and complete dao code which just fetch the etity with entity manager.  Transaction propagation attribute is `Required`

Comment: My understanding is your statements are correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Will same session be used for fetching entities at line1 and line2 ?

yes you are right (assuming you are **not** using [PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED](https://techblog.bozho.net/spring-and-persistencecontexttype-extended/))

> Now if i remove @Transactional(). I believe session will be closed as
>   soon as entity1 is fetched and separate session will be used for
>   line2. Right ?

I don't think so, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311933/spring-managed-transactions-without-transactional-annotation) and [this](http://blog.jhades.org/how-does-spring-transactional-really-work/).

Comment: For first part  I believe `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` is even broader , it means  entity manager (internally session) can survive multiple requests. For second point, its not clear from links you mentioned whether session will be closed or not ? From M.Denim answer looks likes there can be separate sessions(as he mentioned session drainage) but did not mention when session will be closed ?