# JPA persistence context and database operations in Spring

Tags: spring, jpa, persistence

I am working in a Spring project that has to do simple CRUD operations. However, I don't understand how it really works... I have a few questions:

1. Will the JpaRepository methods do the operations in the database exactly when I call them?
2. What is the best way I can execute an insert using JpaRepository and get the response if the insert was or wasn't successful?
3. How does persistence context and when the operations are really done in the database? (ps: a diagram would help a lot)
4. Should I use flush myself or should I let Spring and JPA take care of that for me?

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention: all this questions are easily google able and partly already answered in existing questions.

1 Dependent which operations you use:

- if you have a @Transactional anotation on your method it will commit all operations on the end of the method (of the most top one).
- keep in mind: there are different types of transactions (e.g. requires_new will create suspend the parent then create new after commit of new continue parent)
- if you use .saveAndFush(xx) it will flush it immediatly
- if you don't use explicit transactions it behaves a bit differently

  - [Spring managed transactions without @Transactional annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311933/spring-managed-transactions-without-transactional-annotation)

2 You create an entity + a repository for it and call the .save method
e.g.

```
@Entity
public class Artist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}

public interface ArtistRepository extends JpaRepository<Artist, Long> {}
```

if the insert statement was not successfull it will throw an exception.

3 I think this is already answered with 1

4 I would suggest to use transactions and let spring take care of it, but this highly depends on the needs of your project.

I hope this is a bit of help for you, but you just do a tutorial at first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but one thing is not clear yet. You said that the insert statement would throw an Exception. However, when I do jpaRepository.save(entity_with_a_primary_key_thats_already_in_database) it doesn't throw any Exception

Comment: this is an update then, an example for an exception would be a constraint violation

Comment: what? My question is: why doesn't jpaRepository.save() throw an Exception when the save generates primary key conflicts in the database? And is there a way I can just perform an INSERT and get the result (that is if the insert was successful or not), without having to do a SELECT before?